# Drop down in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

Please provide me the code for the following scenario in HTML:
A table with rows
`row1 
 row2 
 row3`

On selecting row1 the table should provide a drop down row1.1 and row1.2
`row1 
  -row1.1
  -row1.2
 row2 
 row3`

On further selecting row1.1 the table should provide drop down row 1.1.1
`row1 
  -row1.1
     -row1.1.1
  -row1.2
 row2 
 row3`

I am a beginner in HTML. Please guide me through this.

Comment: What? Please reword your question, all I can tell is that you want a HTML table. SO is also for helping with code issues, NOT providing code. Also, You can indent any lines with 4 spaces to create a proper code block. Finally, please use a tool such as [ascii-tables](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: Is this really a question?

Comment: @Leothelion I hope not. it turned up in the review queue and I thought it was a test. Guess not :/

Comment: hahahhaah..some times i felt too that it's test question but beng i reject them and nothing happanes.

Comment: And it is not a test question. I am working on my project and it is part of the project.

Comment: user accordion here's the reference http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you want an `accordian`. It's a stack of rows and when you select one of these rows it expands to a submenu. See [here](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html#/examples)

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I managed to get the code for my situation.
Java Script to perform the dropdown function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
         {
             $('.RowFather').click(function ()
             {
                 $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function()
                 {
                    if ($(this).is('.RowChild'))
                    {
                       $(this).toggle();;
                    } 
                    else if ($(this).is('.RowGrandChild'))
                    {
                       $(this).hide();;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                 });
             });

             $('.RowChild').click(function ()
             {
                 $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function()
                 {
                    if ($(this).is('.RowGrandChild'))
                    {
                       $(this).toggle();;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                 });
             });
             $('.RowFather').nextAll('tr').each( function() {
             if(!($(this).is('.RowFather')))
                 $(this).hide();
            });

         });
```

HTML :

```
<tr class="RowFather">
<td>Father</td>
</tr>
<tr class="RowChild">
<td>child</td>
</tr>
 <tr class="RowGrandChild">
 <td> grandchild</td>
 </tr>
```